# Ubuntu Won't boot from Live CD 14.04.1

Tags: boot, 14.04, live-cd

I downloaded Ubuntu 14.04.1 to help recover a bad hard drive on an old laptop. I downloaded it and burned it to a disc but it doesn't work. I get the little man in the circle, then word Ubuntu on a purplish background and some loading dots. After that I get a black screen with a white bar top then the white bar disappears, then a cursor appears.

I thought it was taking a while to load because of how old the laptop was so I tried it on my HP Envy M6 from late last year and the same thing happened. So I downloaded it again and burned it to a new disc and left it on my M6 while I did my evening shift and I have come back to a black screen with a cursor.

Anyone have any ideas why it's not taking?

Thanks.

Comment: possible duplicate of [My computer boots to a black screen, what options do I have to fix it?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/162075/my-computer-boots-to-a-black-screen-what-options-do-i-have-to-fix-it)

Answer (score 0):

Not sure, but the motherboard could be unsupported as mine is. I would use [UNetbootin](http://unetbootin.sourceforge.net/) to make an install usb and see if that works.

Comment: The old laptop won't boot from USB unfortunately, new one will so I may have to swap the HDD's.

Comment: If you are desperate you could get the files for the old floppy install and upgrade that installation.

Comment: There are ways to make an old computer boot from usb, even if it won't do it by itself. Programs that you boot from floppy which then load the usb, one is called PLOP I think, few others too. No installing to the old HD (if it's old enough it could kill it before you read your data). Easiest to get data is just plug the HD into the computer you're going to copy the data to.